# create a textarea dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want create textarea with javascript when I click on the "yes" radio button in a appropriate div place with id?

```
<div class="controls">
<input type="radio" name="name" id="optionsRadios" value="no" checked><b>NO</b>
<input type="radio" name="name" id="optionsRadios" value="yes" ><b>YES</b>
</div>
<div id="positiontext"></div>
```

help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating & removing the textarea, I would set its display like

```js
function nameChange(el) {
    document.getElementById('positiontext').style.display = el.value == 'yes' ? '' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="optionsRadios" value="no" onchange="nameChange(this)" checked /><b>NO</b>
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="optionsRadios" value="yes" onchange="nameChange(this)" /><b>YES</b>
</div>
<div id="positiontext" style="display: none;">
    <textarea name=""></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by  adding the onclick event to the yes radio button,

```
<input type="radio" name="name" id="optionsRadios" value="yes" onchange="addDIV()">
```

In javascript,

```
<script>
function addDIV() {
    document.getElementById('positiontext').innerHTML = "<input type='textarea' name='myText' />"
}
</script>
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/msuL0yta/160/)

Comment: why do you want to use `innerHTML` ?

Comment: I want create textarea with javascript when I click on the "yes" radio button?

Comment: what i mean is that, using `innerHTML` is a bad thing because for suppose if you want to all more text area to any parent node then first you have to write existing code then you have to add further code and at some point it slowers our application..

Answer (score 0):

i think you should need to do this by using gome function which are specially made for this:

```
<div class="controls">
<input type="radio" name="name" id="optionsRadios" value="no"  checked><b>NO</b>
<input type="radio" name="name" id="optionsRadios" value="yes" onclick="addtxt();" ><b>YES</b>
</div>
<div id="positiontext"></div>
```

### javascript:

```
var addtxt = function(){
 var positiontext(parent) = document.getElementById("positiontext");
 var textarea(child) = document.createElement("textarea");
     textarea(child).addAttribute("style", "(some properties)") //there are other ways also to add some attribute but for now use this

positiontext(parent) .appendChild("textarea(child)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you :D